# How to restore MySQL dump from file in docker container not using pass in terminal

Tags: mysql, docker

I know about [hub docs for mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)
`$ docker exec -i some-mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"' < all-databases.sql`
But problem is that shell gives warning
`[Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.`
and passing this warning  to mysql occurre the error
`ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

I tried to set up .cnf file by copying into container

```
#/etc/mysql/my.cnf
[user]
user=root
password=root
host=localhost
```

Used this command `mysql --login-path=user -uroot -proot`
but `mysql --print-defaults` gives me only socket, not credentials
Also trying set up via `mysql_config_editor`, but `mysql_config_editor: command not found`
So, how can I restore dump?
MySQL version 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Elide the offending line.

```
$ cat all-databases.sql |
  grep -v "Using a password on the command" |
  docker exec -i some-mysql sh ...
```